# Writing to Datastore from Backends without shutting down

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, backend

I am trying to write a program in Google App Engine (Python) to continually run a resident Backend which is working on finding what a series converges to. I want to make it so that it runs in the Backend, writes to Datastore, and at any point in time, you can tell what item the series is on and what value it is. The Backend only writes to one entity in Datastore, so it does not overload the storage or anything.The probably I run into though is that the Backend does not write the entity to the Datastore so it is accessible by my frontend webpage until the Backend is shut down, which defeats the purpose of being able to continually check in on it. If there is some way to have the Backend write to the Datastore so the frontend page can check in on it, please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datastore writes in a backend process should behave no differently than writes in your front end app, meaning that they should be available for read in your front end (nearly) instantly (within consistency constraints).  Both backend and front end interact with the same datastore.

It sounds like you just need to implement a recurring write of the current status of your series (ie. once every x cycles), instead of writing once at the end of the backend process.

Answer (score 0):

You post suggests two issues.

The first is "without shutting down". We don't guarantee that backends will run indefinitely. See [the docs on Shutdown](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Shutdown) for some details.

The second issue, if I'm understanding you, is that you're not seeing values written by the backend until some time after they're written. You may be running into "eventual consistency", were "eventual" is usually pretty short, but can an rare occasions be surprisingly long. Understanding [Isolation and Consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#Isolation_and_Consistency) can help here.